Yup package npm - abortEarly doesn't work as expected
according to yup package of npm, when abortEarly is set to true then it aborts whenever the first error occurs and it returns. But it doesn't return on the first error occurred instead it only returns at the last.
according to yup package of npm, when abortEarly is set to true then it aborts whenever the first error occurs and it returns.
const yup  = require('yup');

const employeeSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required().lowercase(),   // when in strict mode, it checks whether the string is in lowercase
  age: yup.number().positive().integer().required(),
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
  department: yup.string().required(),
  // You can add more fields as needed
});

const employeeData = {
  name: 'john Doe',
  age: '30',
  email: 'john.doe@example.com',
  department:'cse'
  // Additional fields can be added here
};

// Validate employee data against the schema
employeeSchema.validate(employeeData, {
    strict:true,
    abortEarly:true
})
  .then(validatedData => {
    console.log('Validation successful:', validatedData);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Validation error:', error.message);
  });

In my above code, since the name field throws error that the string should be in lowercase and it should abort there and I should receive that error message only. But I receive the last occurred error message which is that 'age must be of only number type' .
Could anyone help why this occurs , also if there is an another way to achieve this then can I know that?
